# Getting a record from a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I want to get the `user_5` (which is the user with id 5) from the `users` collection.

```rb
users = User.all
user_5 = ???
```

I know I can get it with `user = User.find(5)` but I don't want to make another query.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [#find](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find):

```
users = User.all
user_5 = users.find { |user| user.id == 5 }
```

Comment: Your solution did work, but I am waiting for an answer from @mrzasa, maybe he have a point.

Comment: Read the documentation I linked in my answer. It says that "detect and find are two names for the same method."

Comment: Thanks for your fast response @yoones!

Answer (score 1):

Calling

```
users = User.all
```

does not execute the query. The query is executed when you try to iterate over the collection in `find` method It may be faster to call

```
users.find(5)
```

than using in memory `find` because it will fetch all the records from database and iterate over them linerly:

```
users.find { |user| user.id == 5 }
```

Also `users.find` may in fact call the AR `find` not `Enumerable#find`, so the about example could return nothing, it's safer to use [`#detect`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find)

Comment: What is the difference between find and detect?

Comment: @Bengala:  #find and #detect are aliases of the same underlying method. `find` an element to use it or `detect` if an element is present to do something.

Comment: @Bengala find is overridden in ActiveRecord, so if you want to be sure you use `Enumerable#find`, use it's alias - `detect` or call `#to_a` before

Comment: @mrzasa, I selected yoones answer as correct because he posted it first, but your solution works same as hims. One question: In terms of speed, if I have a collection of 500 records, do you recommend to use detect or a normal User.find? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'd chose `User.find`